# Passing C# function return value to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

what i'm doing is, i'm calling a C# function so it returns the data i will use in Javascript,
However when i read the data from javascript it's always undefined, I debugged the C# function and found out that it actually returns the correct data, so i'm thinking i'm only having trouble receiving it from Javascript.

Here is the c# function i'm calling

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static string CommonBus(int StopNo1, int StopNo2)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        LinkedList<int> StopBusNo1 = new LinkedList<int>();
        LinkedList<int> StopBusNo2 = new LinkedList<int>();

        StopBusNo1 = LookForBuses(StopNo1); //Returns the buses that stop at StopNo1
        StopBusNo2 = LookForBuses(StopNo2);

       LinkedList<int> CommonBusNos = LookForCommonBuses(StopBusNo1.First, StopBusNo2.First);// Get common buses that stop at both stops 
       LinkedListNode<int> commonNo = CommonBusNos.First;
       LinkedList<Bus> availableBus = new LinkedList<Bus>();

        while (commonNo != null)
        {
            availableBus.AddLast(GetCommonBusIntel(commonNo.Value, StopNo1, StopNo2));
            commonNo = commonNo.Next;
        }

        return oSerializer.Serialize(availableBus);
    }
```

And here is the Javascipt side

```
      function FindTransportation(startStops, endStops) {

      for (var i = 0; i < startStops.length; i++) {

          for (var x = 0; x < endStops.length; x++) {

              availabeTransports.push(PageMethods.CommonBus(startStops[i].StopNo, endStops[x].StopNo)); // Trying to push the returned data into an array


          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but... Where do you call your server-side WebMethod from your JavaScript client?

Comment: Yes where is your Javascript Ajax request to your WebMethod CommonBus?

Comment: Your web method is named `CommonBus` but your Javascript is calling `LookForCommonBuses`. Is this intentional? If so, I think some code is missing from your example.

Comment: my project is in Turkish, i translated it to English so you can understand it better , so names could be wrong here but the actual code calls the method correctly, it calls the method in javascript at the line availabeTransports.push(PageMethods.CommonBus(startStops[i].StopNo, endStops[x].StopNo));

Comment: You can not call like this, You have to use Ajax to call

Comment: i'm new to asp.net and javascript, i know you use ajax calls to call an url , but how do i exactly call a code behind method with ajax call ? if you could give me an example i would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright found the answer thank you for your comments.

i edited the FindTransportation function

```
   function FindTransportation(length1, length2) {
      for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
          for (var x = 0; x < length2; x++) {                 
              GetCommonBuses(i, x);              
          }
      }
  }
```

and i also created the GetCommonBuses function for ajax calls

```
  function GetCommonBuses(index1,index2) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/HomePage.aspx/CommonBus",
          data: JSON.stringify({ StopNo1: startWalkableStops[index1].StopNo, StopNo2: endWalkableStops[index2].StopNo }),
          contentType: "application/json; charset:utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
      })
          .done(function (res) {
              availabeTransports.push(res);
          });
  }
```